# Attaching/uploading files to not-yet-saved Note - what is best strategy for this?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, azure, file-upload, asp.net-web-api

In my application, I have a textarea input where users can type a note.
When they click Save, there is an AJAX call to Web Api that saves the note to the database.

I would like for users to be able to attach multiple files to this note (Gmail style) before saving the Note. It would be nice if the upload could start as soon as attached, before saving the note.

What is the best strategy for this?

P.S. I can't use jQuery fineuploader plugin or anything like that because I need to give the files unique names on the server before uploading them to Azure.

Is what I'm trying to do possible, or do I have to make the whole 'Note' a normal form post instead of an API call?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This approach is file-based, but you can apply the same logic to Azure Blob Storage containers if you wish.

What I normally do is give the user a unique GUID when they GET the AddNote page. I create a folder called:

```
C:\TemporaryUploads\UNIQUE-USER-GUID\
```

Then any files the user uploads at this stage get assigned to this folder:

```
C:\TemporaryUploads\UNIQUE-USER-GUID\file1.txt
C:\TemporaryUploads\UNIQUE-USER-GUID\file2.txt
C:\TemporaryUploads\UNIQUE-USER-GUID\file3.txt
```

When the user does a POST and I have confirmed that all validation has passed, I simply copy the files to the completed folder, with the newly generated note ID:

```
C:\NodeUploads\Note-100001\file1.txt
```

Then delete the `C:\TemporaryUploads\UNIQUE-USER-GUID` folder

**Cleaning Up**

Now. That's all well and good for users who actually go ahead and save a note, but what about the ones who uploaded a file and closed the browser? There are two options at this stage:

1. Have a background service clean up these files on a scheduled basis. Daily, weekly, etc. This should be a job for Azure's Web Jobs
2. Clean up the old files via the web app each time a new note is saved. Not a great approach as you're doing File IO when there are potentially no files to delete

Comment: This seems like a good solution. My only worry is the overhead, because my Add Note form is located on a Person 'details' page which will be accessed very frequently by multiple users at the same time, so my app will constantly have to create Containers on Azure for the temporary location whenever somebody views that page. Any advice on that? Thanks again.

Comment: I suppose I could move the Add Attachment form to a popup and fire off an AJAX event to create the container before showing the form in the popup..

Comment: Or you could create the container on the first AJAX request? That could return the unique Id for any subsequent requests? Also since this is just temporary storage you might not even have to use blob storage. Just the local web storage as long as you're not expecting a massive amount of requests

Comment: Even better, I could just create a temp container for an 'account' upon account creation and have all user uploads for that account go to that container temporarily. That way I only have to create it once.

Comment: Use a single container and prefix all temp files such that they can be filtered, found, moved or deleted without having to create a new container each time.

Answer (score 2):

Building on RGraham's answer, here's another approach you could take:

- Create a blob container for storing note attachments. Let's call it `note-attachments`.
- When the user comes to the screen of creating a note, assign a GUID to the note.
- When user uploads the file, you just prefix the file name with this note id. So if a user uploads a file say `file1.txt`, it gets saved into blob storage as `note-attachments/{note id}/file1.txt`.
- Depending on your requirement, once you save the note, you may move this blob to another blob container or keep it here only. Since the blob has note id in its name, searching for attachments for a note is easy.

For uploading files, I would recommend doing it directly from the browser to blob storage making use of `AJAX`, `CORS` and `Shared Access Signature`. This way you will avoid data going through your servers. You may find these blog posts useful:

- [Revisiting Windows Azure Shared Access Signature](http://gauravmantri.com/2013/02/13/revisiting-windows-azure-shared-access-signature/)
- [Windows Azure Storage and Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) – Lets Have Some Fun](http://gauravmantri.com/2013/12/01/windows-azure-storage-and-cors-lets-have-some-fun/)